# Spring Cloud Config Server (git) - how to structure yml files

Tags: spring-cloud

Scenario:

we have dev, qa, prod environments and in each one we want to run 2 eureka servers.

so we want to be able to run EurekaServer application with two profiles: dev,eureka1 (on devserver1) and dev,eureka2 (on devserver2) - where eureka1 and eureka2 properties are also environment specific.

If I create following eureka-dev.yml

```
server:
   port: 8761

---
spring:
   profiles: eureka1

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://user:${eureka.password}@devserver2:8761/eureka/ 

---
spring:
   profiles: eureka2

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://user:${eureka.password}@devserver1:8761/eureka/
```

it does not seem to pickup eurekaX profiles. I understand I can create eureka-eureka1.yml and eureka-eureka2.yml, but trying to figure out what is the most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work like that because Spring Boot doesn't (profile specific configuration files cannot themselves contain profile specific content from other profiles). I can see the logic behind it though, so if I were you I'd open a feature request with Spring Boot.

As far as working round it with the existing features goes, if I were you I'd just put everything in one file "eureka.yml". If those files get too large then I suspect there is a different problem.